# in swift how to access to database to GRDB.swft/SQLCipher on signal app fork?

Tags: swift, database, sqlite, sqlcipher, grdb

I'm currently working on a fork from signal messaging app, [here](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS/tree/release/5.22.1) the original 5.22 version my app is coming from. please  take a look at the repo. I'm not the original developer of this fork, and have no experience with databases.

**MORE INFO:**

I want to perform a local encrypted and zipped, backup, in order for the user to store it on a pc, disk or else. I'm doing it by copying database, WAL, attachment and so on, enclosing everything in a file. At this point user already installed app and started the "restore backup" path, all the files of the backup are stored in a new folder.

App is using `GRDB.swift/SQLCipher` pod for managing database.

old DB and new one are crated the same way, I suppose they use same passphrase, set in `Configuration()` init

**GOAL:** I should read the old database and write data to the one the installation just created, selecting what to overwrite (chat) and keep (settings, keys, etc).

since I suppose I should open database session on "imported" database first, I try to do this:

```
do {
var configuration = Configuration()
let dbQueueImported = try DatabaseQueue(path: importedSqlite.path) //here is crashing

//then I don't know what to do, some copy action maybe.

} catch {
print("error \(error)")
}
```

but dbQueueImported triggers this assert

```
extension Database {

//MARK: - database closing

///this method must be called before database deallocation

func close() {

SchedulingWatchdog.precodnitionValidQueue(self)
assert(!isClosed)

//rest of the code....
```

last thing, if I comment the assert I get the error:

```
SQLite error 1 with statement 'SELECT * FROM sqlite_master LIMIT 1': unsupported file format.
```

I suppose I should do something in order to open/close connection

- how should I read/write or copy or even access the databases?
- Is there a way to get a list of tables and columns in order to select the info to be copied?

even if you could tell me if there is someone at signal I could ask for help could be useful

**UPDATE:**

adding a swift error breakpoint I get:

```
2023-09-12 14:28:52:702 Signal[8970:3357545]  [SDSDatabaseStorage.swift:355 write(file:function:line:block:)]: Database write on main thread.
2023-09-12 14:28:52:702 Signal[8970:3357545]  [GRDBDatabaseStorageAdapter.swift:820 dbQueryLog(_:)]: BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION
2023-09-12 14:28:52:704 Signal[8970:3357545]  [GRDBDatabaseStorageAdapter.swift:820 dbQueryLog(_:)]:     INSERT INTO keyvalue (
        key,
        collection,
        value
    ) VALUES ('TSAccountManager_IsTransferInProgressKey', 'TSStorageUserAccountCollection', x'<139 byte>')
    ON CONFLICT (
        key,
        collection
    ) DO UPDATE
    SET value = x'<139 byte>'
```

localized in the throw in Atomics.swift here:

```
extension AtomicValue where T: Equatable {
    // Sets value to "toValue" IFF it currently has "fromValue",
    // otherwise throws.
    public func transition(from fromValue: T, to toValue: T) throws {
        try lock.perform {
            guard self.value == fromValue else {
                throw AtomicError.invalidTransition
            }
            self.value = toValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `assert(!isClosed)` assertion was [removed in GRDB 5.0.3](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#503): consider upgrading your copy of GRDB.

Since you're probably not running GRDB 5, see the migrations guides:

- [Migrating From GRDB 4 to GRDB 5](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/Documentation/GRDB5MigrationGuide.md)
- [Migrating From GRDB 5 to GRDB 6](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/Documentation/GRDB6MigrationGuide.md)

Comment: I cannot, or more precisely, I'm not sure it is possible for me. As you see my project is based upon an old version of signal app. I will check your links, can you help me about reading my imported DB and selectively copy info to new one? I cannot understand how to do it and if I should do something about the passphrase

Comment: The problem with `assert(!isClosed)` is only triggered by databases that fail to open in the first place: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/issues/852. So, if you can not upgrade GRDB, then you have to understand why the `DatabaseQueue` instance fails to be created. I suggest you create a Swift Error Breakpoint in Xcode, so that you can have the debugger pause the program before the assertion kicks it. Very likely, you'll see a "file is not a database" database error, because you do not provide the key to decrypt it. See https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#encryption

Comment: I tried a bit more, I got a different message, I updated the quesiton. consider that the database is generated by the same app, I'm just restoring a database after re-installing the app

Comment: Setting an error breakpoint is good, but it is not enough: look at the error. How could you understand what's wrong if you don't look at the error? Only when you know what's wrong you'll be able to prevent the error from happening (in your application code). It's unfortunate that your app fails opening a connection, because this old GRDB version triggers an assertion. But you have to understand that the error only happens because your app does not open the db correctly. So observe the error, understand it, and fix your app so that this error is not thrown in the first place.

Comment: My issue is right about correctly opening the DB, in theory, I am doing it, I understand that issue is about opening or closing the connection to dv, matter is, I do not know how to correct. I do not have compression of it gRDB / SWLCipher.

Comment: Follow the given advice, and _look at the error_. You can't make any progress if you keep on saying "it fails!". You must upgrade your behavior regarding errors, and be able to tell "it fails with error of type <type>, code <code>, and message <message>. Now that I have read the message, and searched the internet about it, I understand what's wrong, and I was able to fix the error myself!". That's the behavior that will help you going forward.

Comment: I understand what you want to tell me, but since the DB has been working properly for years, the error has no sense to me, and DB cannot be in the wrong format, same reason.  I get this error both with my locally imported db, or with the one generated by app installation. I think the error *unsupported file format* is misleading me. maybe is something about the password or it is not allowed to me open another db file while app is using another one. is the password the one I get with *let keyspec = try keyspec.fetchString()* ?